# ssh remote and calculate sha256 hash :: No such file or directory

Tags: shell, ssh, rhel

I want to connect to remote hosts and there check the sha256sum over some folder:

```
ssh remote_host sha256sum /some_folder/*  > /tmp/some_file.txt
```

and the output is :: `No such file or directory`

`/tmp/some_file.txt` exists in remote host

Any advice or documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not immediately clear what `No such file or directory` refers to, but there are at least two problems:

1. Your local shell tries to expand `/some_folder/*` *locally*. If there is at least one match, the result may include paths that don't exist on the server. If there is no match, the shell may pass `/some_folder/*` to `ssh` literally; then the wildcard will be expanded on the server.

   Even if there are local matches, they may include fragment that will be expanded (or even executed!) on the server. Do you want `/some_folder/*` to be expanded locally in the first place? You probably don't.
2. The redirection (`> /tmp/some_file.txt`) is performed by your local shell and the path is local. It's not clear whether you want this happen locally or on the server.

So you probably want one of the two:

```
ssh remote_host 'sha256sum /some_folder/*'  > /tmp/some_file.txt   # to local file
# or
ssh remote_host 'sha256sum /some_folder/*  > /tmp/some_file.txt'   # to remote file
```

Compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1534401/432690).

Comment: you have saved my life! Appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

Here the redirection happens at the local machine. You need to send the complete command to the remote host:

```
ssh remote_host "sha256sum /some_folder/*  > /tmp/some_file.txt"
```